# Prestashop 1.7 using a lot of memory - How to know what's using memory?

Tags: memory, cpanel, prestashop-1.7

My PS 1.7 is using a lot of memory(6-7GB of a total of 7 GB memory) over an unspecified amount of time.

Is there a way to see what is causing this?

I can see that when indexing all products, either by cron-job or via BO, the memory hits the roof and after the cron-job is done, the memory usage don't decrease back to normal. It stays consistent at a very high numer of usage.

I use cPanel on a shared host, but quite fast and strong server...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the memory usage of individual processes launched from the backoffice, simply activate [debug mode](https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/1.7/basics/installation/configuration/) from the Performance tab and have a check at the Symfony bar at the bottom, which, among other things, also shows the resources usage.

If, on the other hand, you want to check in more detail at a "lower" level, you will need a PHP profiler like [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/), [blackfire](https://www.blackfire.io/) or similar.